# INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK when installing apk

Tags: android

i'm trying to test a project in my phone android 2.3.6 and i get the error message: INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK

the app is about drawing the route between two points;

there is my code:
the xml file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

the java files:

```
            package com.example.getroutexy2;

        import java.util.ArrayList;
        import java.util.List;

        import org.w3c.dom.Document;

        import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
        import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
        import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
        import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
        import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
        import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.PolylineOptions;
        import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
        import com.google.android.maps.Overlay;

        import android.app.ProgressDialog;
        import android.graphics.Color;
        import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
        import android.location.Location;
        import android.location.LocationManager;
        import android.os.AsyncTask;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
        import android.view.Menu;

        public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

            List<Overlay> mapOverlays;
            GeoPoint point1, point2;
            LocationManager locManager;
            Drawable drawable;
            Document document;
            GMapV2GetRouteDirection v2GetRouteDirection;
            LatLng fromPosition;
            LatLng toPosition;
            GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
            MarkerOptions markerOptions;
            Location location ;

            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

                v2GetRouteDirection = new GMapV2GetRouteDirection();
                SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                  .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
                  mGoogleMap = supportMapFragment.getMap();

                  // Enabling MyLocation in Google Map
                  mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                  mGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
                  mGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
                  mGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
                  mGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setAllGesturesEnabled(true);
                  mGoogleMap.setTrafficEnabled(true);
                  mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(12));
                  markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
                  fromPosition = new LatLng(11.663837, 78.147297);
                  toPosition = new LatLng(11.723512, 78.466287);
                  GetRouteTask getRoute = new GetRouteTask();
                  getRoute.execute();
            }

            private class GetRouteTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

                private ProgressDialog Dialog;
                String response = "";
                @Override
                protected void onPreExecute() {
                      Dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
                      Dialog.setMessage("Loading route...");
                      Dialog.show();
                }

                @Override
                protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
                      //Get All Route values
                            document = v2GetRouteDirection.getDocument(fromPosition, toPosition, GMapV2GetRouteDirection.MODE_DRIVING);
                            response = "Success";
                      return response;

                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                      mGoogleMap.clear();
                      if(response.equalsIgnoreCase("Success")){
                      ArrayList<LatLng> directionPoint = v2GetRouteDirection.getDirection(document);
                      PolylineOptions rectLine = new PolylineOptions().width(10).color(
                                  Color.RED);

                      for (int i = 0; i < directionPoint.size(); i++) {
                            rectLine.add(directionPoint.get(i));
                      }
                      // Adding route on the map
                      mGoogleMap.addPolyline(rectLine);
                      markerOptions.position(toPosition);
                      markerOptions.draggable(true);
                      mGoogleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

                      }

                      Dialog.dismiss();
                }
          }
          @Override
          protected void onStop() {
                super.onStop();
                finish();
          }

        }
```

and

```
            package com.example.getroutexy2;

        import java.io.InputStream;
        import java.util.ArrayList;

        import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
        import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

        import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
        import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
        import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
        import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
        import org.apache.http.protocol.BasicHttpContext;
        import org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext;
        import org.w3c.dom.Document;
        import org.w3c.dom.Node;
        import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

        import android.util.Log;

        import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;

        public class GMapV2GetRouteDirection {

            public final static String MODE_DRIVING = "driving";
            public final static String MODE_WALKING = "walking";

            public GMapV2GetRouteDirection() { }

            public Document getDocument(LatLng start, LatLng end, String mode) {
                String url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?"
                        + "origin=" + start.latitude + "," + start.longitude 
                        + "&destination=" + end.latitude + "," + end.longitude
                        + "&sensor=false&units=metric&mode=driving";

                try {
                    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
                    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost, localContext);
                    InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
                    DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
                    Document doc = builder.parse(in);
                    return doc;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }

            public String getDurationText (Document doc) {
                NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("duration");
                Node node1 = nl1.item(0);
                NodeList nl2 = node1.getChildNodes();
                Node node2 = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "text"));
                Log.i("DurationText", node2.getTextContent());
                return node2.getTextContent();
            }

            public int getDurationValue (Document doc) {
                NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("duration");
                Node node1 = nl1.item(0);
                NodeList nl2 = node1.getChildNodes();
                Node node2 = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "value"));
                Log.i("DurationValue", node2.getTextContent());
                return Integer.parseInt(node2.getTextContent());
            }

            public String getDistanceText (Document doc) {
                NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("distance");
                Node node1 = nl1.item(0);
                NodeList nl2 = node1.getChildNodes();
                Node node2 = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "text"));
                Log.i("DistanceText", node2.getTextContent());
                return node2.getTextContent();
            }

            public int getDistanceValue (Document doc) {
                NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("distance");
                Node node1 = nl1.item(0);
                NodeList nl2 = node1.getChildNodes();
                Node node2 = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "value"));
                Log.i("DistanceValue", node2.getTextContent());
                return Integer.parseInt(node2.getTextContent());
            }

            public String getStartAddress (Document doc) {
                NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("start_address");
                Node node1 = nl1.item(0);
                Log.i("StartAddress", node1.getTextContent());
                return node1.getTextContent();
            }

            public String getEndAddress (Document doc) {
                NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("end_address");
                Node node1 = nl1.item(0);
                Log.i("StartAddress", node1.getTextContent());
                return node1.getTextContent();
            }

            public String getCopyRights (Document doc) {
                NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("copyrights");
                Node node1 = nl1.item(0);
                Log.i("CopyRights", node1.getTextContent());
                return node1.getTextContent();
            }

            public ArrayList<LatLng> getDirection (Document doc) {
                NodeList nl1, nl2, nl3;
                ArrayList<LatLng> listGeopoints = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
                nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("step");
                if (nl1.getLength() > 0) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < nl1.getLength(); i++) {
                        Node node1 = nl1.item(i);
                        nl2 = node1.getChildNodes();

                        Node locationNode = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "start_location"));
                        nl3 = locationNode.getChildNodes();
                        Node latNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "lat"));
                        double lat = Double.parseDouble(latNode.getTextContent());
                        Node lngNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "lng"));
                        double lng = Double.parseDouble(lngNode.getTextContent());
                        listGeopoints.add(new LatLng(lat, lng));

                        locationNode = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "polyline"));
                        nl3 = locationNode.getChildNodes();
                        latNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "points"));
                        ArrayList<LatLng> arr = decodePoly(latNode.getTextContent());
                        for(int j = 0 ; j < arr.size() ; j++) {
                            listGeopoints.add(new LatLng(arr.get(j).latitude, arr.get(j).longitude));
                        }

                        locationNode = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "end_location"));
                        nl3 = locationNode.getChildNodes();
                        latNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "lat"));
                        lat = Double.parseDouble(latNode.getTextContent());
                        lngNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "lng"));
                        lng = Double.parseDouble(lngNode.getTextContent());
                        listGeopoints.add(new LatLng(lat, lng));
                    }
                }

                return listGeopoints;
            }

            private int getNodeIndex(NodeList nl, String nodename) {
                for(int i = 0 ; i < nl.getLength() ; i++) {
                    if(nl.item(i).getNodeName().equals(nodename))
                        return i;
                }
                return -1;
            }

            private ArrayList<LatLng> decodePoly(String encoded) {
                ArrayList<LatLng> poly = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
                int index = 0, len = encoded.length();
                int lat = 0, lng = 0;
                while (index < len) {
                    int b, shift = 0, result = 0;
                    do {
                        b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
                        result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                        shift += 5;
                    } while (b >= 0x20);
                    int dlat = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
                    lat += dlat;
                    shift = 0;
                    result = 0;
                    do {
                        b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
                        result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                        shift += 5;
                    } while (b >= 0x20);
                    int dlng = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
                    lng += dlng;

                    LatLng position = new LatLng((double) lat / 1E5, (double) lng / 1E5);
                    poly.add(position);
                }
                return poly;
            }

        }
```

finally the manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       package="com.example.getroutexy2"
     android:versionCode="1"
     android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="7"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<permission
    android:name="com.example.getroutexy2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.example.getroutexy2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.getroutexy2.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyCkdoZ..............." />

</application>
```

thanks, for the key i'm sure it's a good one

Answer (score 8):

Either:

- Your device is not running Android 2.3.6, or
- Your application does not have this manifest, or
- You are misinterpreting something, or
- Your device or app is very strange

`INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK` should only occur if the API level of the device is below your `android:minSdkVersion`. In your case, `android:minSdkVersion` is `7`, which is Android 2.1. Hence, you should not be getting this error.

Comment: the error is launched when Uploading GoogleMapsAndroidv2.apk onto device. did google-play-services-lib has anything to do with this ?

Comment: @Med_mofid You should edit your question to include this information.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Android studio, beside the manifest file:

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
```

you must change grandle.build file too

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 16
    }
}
```

Comment: He does not seem to be using android studio.

Comment: That's indepedent of use of Android Studio or not.

Answer (score 0):

Check you have the min required and/or the target version SDK installed with `android sdk`, under "Tools" look for the build tool with matching "Rev."; and matching API version section (i.e. `Android 4.4.2 (API 19)` for SDK 19.

Answer (score -2):

Fragments were not made avilailable until API level 11 hence android 2.3.6 cannot run it

Comment: The app is using the Android Support package's backport of fragments.

Comment: No its working, i used it before and it works fine

Comment: Oh okay. I hadn't realised MapSupportFragment was part of support API for backward compatibility.  What you could do is try and change the MinSDK lower, maybe 5, and see if that installs. Are you using any new external jar's? That could well be causing the issue

Comment: The problem appears when Installing GoogleMapsAndroidv2.apk i don't know the reason!