# Android studio running issue - Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK]

Tags: android, android-studio

when I wanna running the app, I click on the run button and then I get an error that says:

> pkg: /data/local/tmp/com.google.eilat.yonatan.sunshine
>   Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK

Someone knows how to alive it?
Hope for answers :)

Comment: What is your min SDK? Are you defining it in your build.gradle or your manifest (or both)?

Comment: It should be defined in your build.gradle. I would just update your question with the entire contents of the `android {}` section. Also be sure to post what API version the device you are trying to install to is running.

Comment: Im trying to do it on my nexus 4 on MacBook Air

Comment: Check out my build.gradle: http://prntscr.com/3ye2il

Comment: I'm running on my nexus 4 the version 4.4.4 what's the API level?

Comment: 4.4.x is API 19, so you shouldn't be getting this error unless you are targeting 20+, which I highly doubt.

Comment: If you update your build.gradle to use `compileSdkVersion 19` and `targetSdkVersion 19`, does the problem go away?

Comment: Note to the reopen voters: This question does **NOT** duplicate [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK when installing apk](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16342280/install-failed-older-sdk-when-installing-apk). This problem is caused by targeting the L preview, not by trying to use a newer SDK with an older device.

Answer (score 0):

update your minsdk and target versions

not sure what it was before but it appears to be less than what you had before

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" android:targetSdkVersion="15"/>
```

Comment: I tried, doesnt work.

Comment: If you are using Gradle and you have your min SDK defined in your build.gradle, you should not also have a `<uses-sdk>` element in your manifest.

Comment: That's my build.gradle: http://prntscr.com/3ye2il
I dont know about all this because I just started the whole apps thing.

Comment: You should have another build.gradle one folder deeper. The one you posted is the project-wide build.gradle, not the Android module build.gradle.

Comment: Oh you're right.
http://prntscr.com/3ye6mv

Answer (score 0):

Your build.gradle specifies the Android L preview as the `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion`. Unless you are intentionally testing your application with the L developer preview, you should not be targeting and compiling with it.

I believe that applications that target/compile the L preview can *only* be run on devices running the L preview.

Update your build.gradle like so and the problem should go away:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 19

    defaultConfig {
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }
}
```

Comment: When I update thetargetSdkVersion I get an error with Cradle syncing

Comment: What is the error? Do you have the API 19 SDK installed in the SDK manager?

Comment: No, but when im trying to install it: http://prntscr.com/3ygkxb
and I have connection to the internet.